# Grouping Xcode schemes

Tags: ios, xcode

We have lot of Xcode schemes in our project and at times it becomes difficult to identify and choose the correct one. Is there a way we can group schemes so as to quickly identify and choose them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way we can group schemes so as to quickly identify and choose them?

**No**, there's no mechanism built into Xcode for grouping schemes. You can, however, arrange the schemes in the list as you see fit, so you could order the schemes such that they happen to to be in groups. Just open the scheme manager and drag the schemes into whatever order you prefer. It might help to agree on some kind of naming convention so that related schemes all start with the same word and are easy to pick out.

You could also look at not sharing all your schemes. If the number of schemes is large because different people need different schemes, consider not checking the "Shared" checkbox in the scheme manager for schemes that are only used by one person.